# No Module named '_cffi_backend' while using cryptography

Tags: python-3.x, django, cryptography, cffi

I'm using the "cryptography" library in my Django web app and facing 'Module Not Found Error: No Module named '_cffi_backend' in my server log. I've upgraded my Python version from Python3.6 to Python3.9 and using a virtual environment. I've uninstalled all related libraries (i.e. cryptography, cffi, paramiko and etc) and reinstalled them again but still facing the same error.

This error is happening after the below line in the terminal.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
```

Below are my environment details

RHEL7.9, Python3.9, Django-3.11, cryptography-3.3.1, cffi-1.15.1

Comment: I recently faced this error: No Module named '_cffi_backend'. Upgrading cffi and cryptography worked for me.

pip3 install --upgrade cffi cryptography